# Session Time out handling in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I have a problem regarding the Session Timeout handling in Spring Security in our spring application. Actually the application is configure for 1 hour session timeout in SiteMinder. So after 1 hour, the application session is timed out. After session time out if we do any operation on the page, instead of redirecting the user to invalidsession.jsp, as its configured in our security-context.xml file. Currently when we click on the submit button a search button, an ajax call is made and its giving a wrong message saying records are not found, which is confusing for the user. How to handle this issue in such a way that after session time out, instead of ajax call, the application should redirect to invalidsession.jsp

Comment: Can you show some ajax code call and server code

Comment: What does the response look like when it times out? I'm guessing the issue is that Siteminder is redirecting you to the login page since it intercepts the request before the request makes it to Spring Security.

Comment: The response was a pop up box showing Error loading UserDetails, which is caused since in the search javascript file we are calling loadUserDetails which is an ajax call and which has a corresponding controller and that fails due to session timeout, and gives error to ui layer.